# How to avoid certain content being placed alone on a page with iText7?

Tags: java, itext7

At the end of the final page I want to print a signature. There are situations where the length of the document makes the signature and only the signature to get printed onto the next page. It is not nice to have a whole page with only a signature on it while all the report is in the previous pages.

Has anyone faced these problems before and have found a working solution?

Thanks in advance,

Toutoudakis Michail

Comment: Please could you show what you've written so far? Could you please expand a bit on "I tried to do it with headers but i couldn't make it work correct. I fixed it for a specific report, but on different reports with different length the displacement was awful"?

Comment: As for your second problem: what would be the desired behavior for you? If you cannot place the signature on the last page (and need to create a new one), do you want to move some content to the next page as well as the signature?

Comment: Yes moving some content would be the easiest solution but how can i know that only signatures exist on the last page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for your second question, please consider using `setKeepTogether` or `setKeepWithNext` methods.

Let's look at either approach:

1) `setKeepTogether` has been designed to keep the container's children together as much as possible. That mean that iText will not split the container and will move the whole container to the net page unless the container could'n be placed there as well.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 28; i++) {
        doc.add(new Paragraph("\n"));
    }

    Div div = new Div();
    div.add(new Paragraph("Please, keep me with the next element").setKeepWithNext(true));
    div.add(new Paragraph("I don't want to be alone!"));

    div.setKeepTogether(true);

    doc.add(div);
```

The result pdf looks as follows (note that there is enough space for the "please" paragrapg on the first page):
[image]

2) `setKeepWithNext` has been designed to keep the end of the first element and the start of its next sibling on the same area.
(!) Please note this will only work for high-level elements, i.e. elements added to the root element.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 28; i++) {
        doc.add(new Paragraph("\n"));
    }

    doc.add(new Paragraph("Please, keep me with the next element").setKeepWithNext(true));
    doc.add(new Paragraph("I don't want to be alone!"));
```

The result is the same.

As for your first question, I'm really eager to see what you have writen. I believe that using events you would be able to achieve what you desire. Please take a look at the next iText samples: https://github.com/itext/i7js-examples/tree/develop/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/samples/sandbox/events and https://github.com/itext/i7js-examples/blob/develop/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/samples/sandbox/events/VariableHeader.java in particular.

Also for a smarter layout I can suggest that you use `Canvas` (and therefore highlevel api) rather than `PdfCanvas` (as in the mentioned samples).
Still this feels like a different question.

Comment: Div with  setKeepTogether(true) worked like a charm for not allowing signatures to be printed alone on a blank page. However i am still struggling with the first of my problems... I will post more info as soon as i try the samples you mentions above. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I 've read the examples you mentioned but my header is kind of a paragraph with graphics or a Div Container with text and images. The examples refer only to text and i haven't figured out yet how someone can import a Div or Paragraph to pdfCanvas. Any suggestions??

Comment: Since it's a bit separate question, could you create a new ticket for that problem?
I have a solution for it as well, but I just don't want this answer to get messy

Comment: I've already answered it.

As for this question: please accept the answer if you're satisfied with it